# Single 2x8 Wall For Back-to-Back Bathrooms with Wall Mount Toilets

Tags: plumbing, toilet, drain-waste-vent

House has 2 bathrooms with mirrored fixtures on either side of the “wall”.  Currently, this is framed as 2 separate walls with a small chaise in between.  Due to the small dimensions in the owner’s bath and the framing needing to be replaced between the 2 bathrooms already, I’m considering reframing as a single 2x8 wall with no chaise.  As part of this remodel, I’d also like to install wall-mount toilets with the Geberit DuoFix wall tank for 2x4 construction (product - https://www.geberitnorthamerica.com/products/installation-systems/systems-for-wall-hung-toilets/for-2x4-construction/) (installation manual - https://www.geberitnorthamerica.com/_assets/local-media/instructions/968-075-00-0-sigma2x4-install.pdf).

[image: existing]

- any concerns with changing this to a single 2x8 wall?

  - not concerned with sound isolation
- Any concerns with the in-wall tanks being back-to-back

  - Would it make sense to create separate dwv branches for each bathroom to make it easier to connect each wall-mount toilet?
    [example separate branches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptNJx.jpg)

Comment: "For 3½" max. wall thickness Vertical drainage only --- For 5½" min. wall thickness For RH, LH and vertical drainage" - wold need to open the ceiling below to do the drain(s). Otherwise (**I would call them**) it needs to be an actual dimensional 2x10 *plus* an inch of furring. Prob can't/shouldn't tee them right at their outputs. So even b-t-b sharing a vertical drain is a nope.

Comment: If they must be b-t-b then they both basically need their own 2x6 (For 5½" min) wall if they're going to turn before dropping through the floor. I don't see anyway to do it other than with the two separate drains as you drew that go down and then find a pipe to tie into. - "To install tank and carrier, a 2 x 4" wood frame or metal frame construction is required. Studs must be placed 19 3/ 4" apart" - Is a 2x8 *actually* the same thing as two 2x4s?

Comment: Can you not offset the toilets and use a tee/wye to a shared drain?

Comment: 2 x 4" dimensional is actually 3-1/2", (2) 2x4" would then be 7".  2x8" dimensional is 7-1/4", so my understanding is 2x8" would actually give 1/4" more space than (2) 2x4".  I forgot to mention this is a single level home with crawl space below.